# Adding an x:Key attribute using Linq to Xml

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to set x:Key in some XAML using Linq to XML so I can add a value converter to the resource dictionary of a data template:

```
 XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
 XNamespace local = "clr-namespace:App,assembly=App";
 XElement dt = new XElement(xmlns + "DataTemplate",
     new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"),
     new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "local", "clr-namespace:App,assembly=App"),
     new XElement(xmlns + "DataTemplate.Resources",
         new XElement(local + "MyConverter",
             new XAttribute("x:Key", "myConverter"))));
```

However this raises an exception complaining that ':' is not allowed in attribute names. Using another `XNamespace x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"` and writing `x + "Key"` doesn't work either - it gives `p3:Key`.

Is there some way to include a colon in `XAttribute` names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
    XNamespace local = "clr-namespace:App,assembly=App";
    XNamespace x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; 

    XElement dt = new XElement(xmlns + "DataTemplate",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "local", "clr-namespace:App,assembly=App"),
        new XElement(xmlns + "DataTemplate.Resources",
            new XElement(local + "MyConverter",
                new XAttribute(x + "Key", "myConverter"))));

   Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output:

```
<DataTemplate xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App,assembly=App" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
  </DataTemplate.Resources>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: As noted in the question, that doesn't work. It gives, in this case, `p0:Key="myConverter"`.

Comment: You're right, it does work, thanks. Turns out I had a naming mismatch between the xmlns:local and local.